# Dynamically update inline css using React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a component '**ResolutionChooser**' which receives width and height from a user. '**ResolutionChooser**' has a button, and when the user clicks submit, it calls on the callback, supplying the width and the height. The parent '**TopNode**' updates itself with the width and height and re-renderings of the children are triggered.

I have a div belonging to the child **WrapperObject** where I set the inline style. I want it to change each time the user changes the resolution. The dims set in the constructor of '**TopNode**' registers, and changing those and reloading the application gives me the look I want - except I want to change it dynamically.

> The exact dims are not known, so I want the users to be able to choose
> them as they please.

What am I overlooking here? Is it the inline styles that are the problem?
If so, what alternative ways can I solve this problem?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dims: {
        width: 500,
        height: 100
      }
    };
    this.onWidthUpdate = this.onWidthUpdate.bind(this);
    this.onHeightUpdate = this.onHeightUpdate.bind(this);
  }

  onWidthUpdate = event => {
    let dims = { width: event.target.value, height: this.state.dims.height };
    this.setState({ dims: dims });
  };

  onHeightUpdate = event => {
    let dims = { width: this.state.dims.width, height: event.target.value };
    this.setState({ dims: dims });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container-one">
          <ResolutionChooser
            dims={this.state.dims}
            onWidthUpdate={this.onWidthUpdate}
            onHeightUpdate={this.onHeightUpdate}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="container-two">
          <WrapperComponent dims={this.state.dims} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class WrapperComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    let width = this.props.dims.width;
    let height = this.props.dims.height;
    return (
      <div
        className="simple-border-with-background"
        style={{ width: this.props.dims.width, height: this.props.dims.height }}
      >
        {this.props.dims.width} x {this.props.dims.height}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function ResolutionChooser(props) {
  return (
    <div className="input">
      Width:
      <input
        type="number"
        defaultValue={props.dims.width}
        onChange={props.onWidthUpdate}
      />
      Height:
      <input
        type="number"
        defaultValue={props.dims.height}
        onChange={props.onHeightUpdate}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

> **Expected:**
>
> inline style to update to the dimensions given by the user
>
> **Actual:**
>
> Inline styles does not update, event though re-rendering is triggered and the expected values are logged to the console within the component's render call

Relevant codesandbox: [updated running example which illustrates my problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-chaplygin-fcsgz?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Here's the working code:

```
class WrapperComponent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    let width = Number(JSON.parse(this.props.dims.width));
    let height = Number(JSON.parse(this.props.dims.height));

    return (
      <div
        className="simple-border-with-background"
        style={{ width, height}}
      >
        {width} x {height}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I removed the constructor as it is unneeded when you don't have a state. You declared the variables width and height, but they weren't being used. I updated the style to use those variables. I parsed the JSON so we get a string of the user input, and then we convert it to a number. Code works now. :)

Reviewing the problem initially:
Ah, I see the issue. If you console.log the props after hitting the submit button, you don't get a value you get [object HTMLInputElement]. Take a look at React controlled forms: https://itnext.io/how-to-build-a-dynamic-controlled-form-with-react-hooks-2019-b39840f75c4f

Comment: Hmm, I can see that it causes an error in the codesandbox. 
I don't know why that is, as it logs and renders as it should on my computer (no complaining from react either)

Comment: And also, you made me aware of a bug in my codesandbox and the attached code. But unfortunately, that bug is not in the application I'm developing. I'll update the original post.

Comment: Got it working, I'll upload the code in a second.
It's not causing an issue in your local because you're using JSON.stringify to convert it to a string to read it, but you're not passing in the stringified version to the style inputs. You can't pass a string, it has to be a number, and trying to convert the JSON string > number keeps turning it into NaN for me. When passing a string/NaN to a div, it doesn't use the input amounts, it just uses a default. This explains why your initial values work, but any future inputs don't.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an onChange handler on your inputs. Try adding the onChange handler at it should work.

Comment: I have updated the codesandbox. The issue still persists unfortunately.